# How to convert a date string with ordinal suffix to another format?

Tags: date, powershell, ordinal

I have a bunch of files that all have a name format like:

```
'This is an example filename - 1st September 2013'
'This is an example filename - 23rd October 2013'
```

Using PowerShell I'd like to rename the files like so:

```
'File-20130901'
'File-20131023'
```

The part I'm having trouble with is converting the date string to a recognised date format.

With a date string that was a recognised format I would do something like:

```
PS> $date = '23 October 2013'
PS> Get-Date $date -Format 'yyyyMMdd'
```

But I'm having trouble with these date strings because of the ordinal month-day suffixes.

How would you approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regex to remove the ordinal. Here is an example:

```
(Get-Date ('23rd October 2013' -replace '(\d+)(\w+)(.+)', '$1$3')).ToString('\File-yyyyMMdd')
```